# Get Structured Data from HTML using python and beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I an new to python. I want to get the result of the code as below:

```
Score      Postive        Negative
  5         good            bad
  7       interesting
  3                       horrible
```

But my code output nothing.Please where is the problem?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
text = """
... <body>
        <div class="review">
        <p class="pos">good</p>
        <p class="neg">bad</p>
    </div>
    <div class="review">
        <p class="pos">interesting</p>
    </div>
    <div class="review">
        <p class="neg">horrible</p>
    </div>
... </body>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
for parent in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'review'}):   
if parent.findNextSiblings('p', attrs={'class': 'pos'}):
    postive.append(parent.get_text())
else:
    postive.append("")
if parent.findNextSiblings('p', attrs={'class': 'neg'}): 
    negtive.append(parent.get_text())
else:
    negtive.append("")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p` tags are not siblings of the `div` tag with class `review`, they are children:

```
positive = []
negative = []
for div in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'review'}):
    pos = div.find('p', {'class': 'pos'})
    positive.append(pos.get_text() if pos else '')

    neg = div.find('p', {'class': 'neg'})
    negative.append(neg.get_text() if neg else '')

print positive
print negative
```

Prints:

```
[u'good', u'interesting', ''] 
[u'bad', '', u'horrible']
```